# Blocking socket - waitForReadyRead()

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

Currently in my QT code I have something like this:

```
QByteArray tick_stream;
clntSocket->waitForReadyRead();
tick_stream = clntSocket->read(800);
```

In the documentation it states

> This function blocks until new data is available for reading and the
>   readyRead() signal has been emitted. The function will timeout after
>   msecs milliseconds; the default timeout is 30000 milliseconds

Is there any way I can make waitForReadyRead wait till infinity in my blocking applicaton

Comment: By giving a really really large timeout?

Answer (score 6):

You can use `-1` as the parameter to wait indefinately.

```
clntSocket->waitForReadyRead(-1);
```

This is in the documentation for `QIODevice` but not the derived socket classes.

Really however you should use the Qt event loop and attach a slot to the `readyRead` signal rather than blocking a thread.

Comment: If it's a dedicated thread, blocking should be fine - only thing problematic might be when trying to quit the thread properly while it's blocked.

Comment: There's obviously nothing techincally wrong with blocking a thread, but it would be more consistant with the Qt design pattern to use the signal.  Whether you agree with the Qt design pattern is a different matter? :)

Comment: Just because you can use a signal, that doesn't mean you have to :) Just as just because there's QObject, you don't have to make everything a QObject (in fact, you shouldn't).

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld, it seems that [waitForReadyRead()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead) function has some problem on Windows OS according to Qt official documentation. Though I was testing on Linux, I observed some irregularities. My code was actually implemented in regular C sockets and I ported to Qt. Hence, in this particular case using SIGNAL/SLOT seems better.